# Adding cells and rows programmatically to a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a loop that runs through all of a user's address book contacts. It checks to see if any of the user's contact's phone numbers are in my server's database. The database returns an object to me that has a count property, and if the phone number was found in the database, then the object returns with a count of 1.

I need to add code to this loop, so that any time the object returns with a count of 1, a new cell and row are added to the UITableView that has already been created in the story board.

I have some method implementations already setup to control the UITableView but I can only get them to work for 1 contact and that is it. These were copied from a tutorial and I just can't get them to work for my specific purpose. I have also played around with some code from the iOS docs but I'm lost.

Isn't there a simple way to programmatically add additional cells and rows to a UITableView that has already been created in the storyboard?

Comment: you have to update the data source and reload the table view

Comment: your table view definitely depends on some array for creation of cells?? add new value to the array and call reloadData method of uitableviewcell, a new cell will automatically be inserted

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add dynamic row then the simplest way to add new data in array in which yo have store data for creating rows and then call for reload of table, it will add new rows in you table.

Comment: How can I add a new value to the array every time my loop runs through without deleting the arrays other values?

Comment: @user3344977 such as using a mutable array and call `- (void)addObject:(id)anObject` ?

Comment: Ok, I will keep adding an aditional entry to the mutable array, and refresh the UITableView every time.

Comment: @user3344977 yes you can use  - (void)addObject:(id)anObject to add value in array